# How to Integrate SAML Browser Authentication with a Java Web Start Application

Tags: java, security, java-web-start, jnlp, spring-saml

We have a web application which is deployed in tomcat server. All the browser request has been authenticated by SAML SSO to access the backend services. Now we are trying to invoke Java Web Start application which is been invoked by clicking on the hyperlink from web application's . JWS application is loaded successfuly and issue occurs while accessing the backend services as stated below.

Issue: Java web start application needs to invoke some of the backend webservices which requires the SAML authentication token to access those services. Does any one come across this issue or any have idea how to resolve this? Your inputs really appreciated.

How to integrate SAML authentication in JWS?